# Get a pointer to STL container an iterator is referencing?

Tags: c++, stl

For example, the following is possible:

```
std::set<int> s;  
std::set<int>::iterator it = s.begin();
```

I wonder if the opposite is possible, say,

```
std::set<int>* pSet = it->**getContainer**();  // something like this...
```

Comment: I'm interested to know why you want this.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to save the state of the iterator during some traversal (of some other data structure) so I can increment the iterator in the next visit. If the above is possible then I don't have to keep the reference/pointer to the container itself but only the pointer to that iterator.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, there is no portable way to do this.

An iterator may not even have a reference to *the container*.  For example, an implementation could use `T*` as the `iterator` type for both `std::array<T, N>` and `std::vector<T>`, since both store their elements as arrays.

In addition, iterators are far more general than containers, and not all iterators point into containers (for example, there are input and output iterators that read to and write from streams).

Comment: This is old but I have a very small question. Assuming that an iterator (not necessarily from STL) did originate from a container, it may or may not possess a pointer/reference to its originating containter. But if it does, then the type of the container, and the container itself, are absolutely known to the user of the iterator, are they not? Unless the pointer/reference to the container is defined to be private, of course, but why would the programmer want to hide this?

Answer (score 8):

No.  You must remember the container that an iterator came from, at the time that you find the iterator.

A possible reason for this restriction is that pointers were meant to be valid iterators and there's no way to ask a pointer to figure out where it came from (e.g. if you point 4 elements into an array, how from that pointer alone can you tell where the beginning of the array is?).

Answer (score 6):

It is possible with at least one of the `std` iterators and some trickery.
The `std::back_insert_iterator` needs a pointer to the container to call its `push_back` method. Moreover this pointer is `protected` only.

```
#include <iterator>

template <typename Container>
struct get_a_pointer_iterator : std::back_insert_iterator<Container> {
    typedef std::back_insert_iterator<Container> base;
    get_a_pointer_iterator(Container& c) : base(c) {}
    Container* getPointer(){ return base::container;}
};

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::vector<int> x{1};
    auto p = get_a_pointer_iterator<std::vector<int>>(x);
    std::cout << (*p.getPointer()).at(0);
}
```

This is of course of no pratical use, but merely an example of an `std` iterator that indeed carries a pointer to its container, though a quite special one (eg. incrementing a `std::back_insert_iterator` is a noop). The whole point of using iterators is not to know where the elements are coming from. On the other hand, if you ever wanted an iterator that lets you get a pointer to the container, you could write one.