# STL map output iterator lookup value

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iterator, output

I am trying to make a function that is generic and takes an output iterator to any container type (that is, a particular kind of map regardless of allocator).

However, I would like to know whether the map referenced by itOut already contains an element, and if so, update it

```
template<typename OutputIterator>
static void foo(const std::wstring& rstr, OutputIterator itOut)
{
    // Insert two items into the map that itOut references
    itOut++ = TokenPair(t, 1);
    itOut++ = TokenPair(t, 2);

    // This here I don't know how to do
    if(somehow check the map already contains t)
    {
        map[t] = 5;
    }
}
```

Surely there must be a way for this?

It seems to be the best way because other parts of the program are trying to pass maps that have **identical pairs, but different allocators.**

Comment: Why can't you pass the map and have the map type as a template parameter?

Comment: standard iterator don't support such operators. See the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/) on types of iterators and what kind of operations they support. Even simple pointer can serve as iterator and there is no way to access the actual container. You would have to provide the map as third argument of the function

Comment: That's a good question, seems like I omitted that. Earlier today I had a reason why this wasn't possible and I discarded that idea. I'll double check and get back to you.

Comment: That's what I was worried about because I read this in these similar problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017051/obtain-container-type-from-its-iterator-type-in-c-stl and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445025/get-a-pointer-to-stl-container-an-iterator-is-referencing

Comment: Ok, why, for some reason, I discarded this earlier I don't remember, but this is a great idea actually. If someone wishes to phrase this as an answer, I'm happy to give credit!

Comment: You should reply to people in the comments with "@AndyProwl" for example, otherwise nobody knows who exactly you're talking to, and the person in question also won't get notified without it.

Comment: why not something like this: use two iterators (maybe copy itOut at the beginning) and then do a find_if, where the value is a TokenPair and the comparison operator compares the keys only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with the solution that Andy Prowl suggested, where the method is templated to take the appropriate map type. That way the allocator becomes irrelevant.