# Compiling errors std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> iterator and erase methods

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, stdvector

I'm trying to make a game with C++ and SFML. However, I have some issues with the `Missile` class. I have a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Missile>>`, and what I would like to do is remove missiles when they are out of range.

I've made some research on StackOverflow and I found something like this:

```
auto list = ship->getMissilesToDisplay(); // returns the std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Missile>>
auto iterator = std::find(list.begin(), list.end(), [](const std::shared_ptr<Missile>& m) { return m->canDelete(); });
list.erase(iterator);
```

But when I compile this, I get some errors:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\xutility(3579): error C2678: binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::shared_ptr<Missile>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\system_error(284): note: could be 'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_condition &,const std::error_condition &) noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\system_error(278): note: or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_condition &,const std::error_code &) noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\system_error(272): note: or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_code &,const std::error_condition &) noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\system_error(266): note: or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_code &,const std::error_code &) noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\exception(330): note: or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::exception_ptr &,std::nullptr_t) noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\exception(325): note: or       'bool std::operator ==(std::nullptr_t,const std::exception_ptr &) noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\exception(320): note: or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::exception_ptr &,const std::exception_ptr &) noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\memory(1615): note: or       'bool std::operator ==<Missile>(const std::shared_ptr<Missile> &,std::nullptr_t) noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\xutility(3579): note: or       'built-in C++ operator==(bool (__cdecl *)(const std::shared_ptr<Missile> &), bool (__cdecl *)(const std::shared_ptr<Missile> &))'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\xutility(3579): note: or       'built-in C++ operator==(bool (__stdcall *)(const std::shared_ptr<Missile> &), bool (__stdcall *)(const std::shared_ptr<Missile> &))'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\xutility(3579): note: or       'built-in C++ operator==(bool (__fastcall *)(const std::shared_ptr<Missile> &), bool (__fastcall *)(const std::shared_ptr<Missile> &))'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\xutility(3579): note: or       'built-in C++ operator==(bool (__vectorcall *)(const std::shared_ptr<Missile> &), bool (__vectorcall *)(const std::shared_ptr<Missile> &))'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\xutility(3579): note: while trying to match the argument list '(std::shared_ptr<Missile>, const Game::clean::<lambda_42809c80e7e2bc392c11a08cf362033b>)'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\xutility(3592): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_InIt std::_Find_unchecked1<_InIt,_Ty>(_InIt,const _InIt,const _Ty &,std::false_type)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _InIt=std::shared_ptr<Missile> *,
1>            _Ty=Game::clean::<lambda_42809c80e7e2bc392c11a08cf362033b>
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\xutility(3601): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_InIt std::_Find_unchecked<std::shared_ptr<Missile>*,_Ty>(const _InIt,const _InIt,const _Ty &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _InIt=std::shared_ptr<Missile> *,
1>            _Ty=Game::clean::<lambda_42809c80e7e2bc392c11a08cf362033b>
1>        ]
1>c:\users\thàng long\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\asteroid\asteroid\src\game.cpp(13): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_InIt std::find<std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>,Game::clean::<lambda_42809c80e7e2bc392c11a08cf362033b>>(_InIt,const _InIt,const Game::clean::<lambda_42809c80e7e2bc392c11a08cf362033b> &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _InIt=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<std::shared_ptr<Missile>>>>,
1>            _Ty=std::shared_ptr<Missile>
1>        ]
```

Maybe I misunderstood how to implement this code?

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `std::find` with a unary predicate, but `std::find` expects a value type to test for equality there. Thus, you're trying compare `std::shared_ptr<Missile>` with a lambda, which is impossible, of course, and results in the typically horrible template error message. You probably want to use [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), which accepts a predicate:

```
std::find_if(list.begin(), list.end(), [](const std::shared_ptr<Missile>& m) { return m->canDelete(); });
```

EDIT: The above solution will let you remove the *first* Missile that can be deleted. If you want to delete *every* Missile that can be deleted, you can use [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove). It's usage comes with a confusing idiom but I'll try to explain. `std::remove_if` also takes two iterators and a unary predicate, but it doesn't actually *remove* elements (because to do this, it would need to be aware of the container given only iterators, which is [impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445025/get-a-pointer-to-stl-container-an-iterator-is-referencing)). Instead, it *shuffles* elements to the back of the container if they should be removed, and returns a new iterator to the first of those elements. This is coupled with `std::vector::erase(iterator first, iterator last);` to delete those trailing elements. Now for the actual code, with indenting to help separate the moving parts:

```
list.erase(
    std::remove_if(
        list.begin(),
        list.end(),
        [](const std::shared_ptr<Missile>& m){ m->canDelete(); }
    ),
    list.end()
);
```

Comment: sorry, in my edition, I write "unique_ptr" by mistake. If you accept it, remember to correct it, thanks...

Comment: Hi, I tried this, it compiles now! However, my missiles which are out of range aren't removed. My game is becoming slower, each time I shoot...

Comment: That’s probably related to other logic you’re written elsewhere, and would be beyond the scope of this question. I suggest you spend some time debugging and thinking about your design and if you encounter something specific that you don’t know how to fix, ask feel free to another question.

Comment: Though about missiles not being removed; does `ship->getMissilesToDisplay();` return a vector of missiles by _value_? If so, any changes to that vector will not be seen by `ship`. Maybe you should pass the vector by reference or move this logic into `ship` entirely